# How to config Spring to load hibernate mapping from jar?

Tags: hibernate, spring

My hibernate mapping is in a jar file for example: abc-1.0.1.jar. And the mapping files are: abc-1.0.1.jar/user.hbm.xml.

I can't get spring to load it correctly (I don't want to put my jar version in the mapping also). This is my configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="DS"/></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
        </property>     
        <property name="mappingJarLocations" value="classpath*:abc-*.jar"></property>
    </bean>
```

There is no error at loading but the setting resource is an empty array. Can you help me figure out that is wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you might want to use `mappingLocations` ([JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setMappingLocations%28org.springframework.core.io.Resource%5b%5d%29)) property, instead of `mappingJarLocations`. In that case, you would just specify `classpath:user.hbm.xml`:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="DS"/></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:/user.hbm.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the "it doesn't work" part? what exactly doesn't work? what error do you get? etc

Comment: this works. I made a mistake in putting mappingJarLocations instead of mappingLocations. Thanks

Comment: This will only works for specified `hbm.xml` not for `*.hbm.xml`, If there are all files that ends with `hbm.xml`, then we need to use `mappingJarLocations`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard:

```
<property name="mappingJarLocations" value="WEB-INF/lib/abc-*.jar"/>
```