# Maven dependency not visible in Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a depedency project called myjar. I installed it in my local Maven repository.

Then in my main project, I included the dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I have some Spring configuration in my main project where I want to refer to the dependency jar:

```
<list>
    <value>myjar-1.0.jar</value>
</list>
```

But the above line of code doesn't work.

However I don't want to create a uber-jar with all the dependencies, I just want my dependency to be accessed from  the local repository.

So how should I rewrite the above Spring configuration in order to do that?

Comment: What kind of Spring configuration would need to refer to a JAR?

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingJarLocations">
       <list>
         <value>myjar-1.0.jar</value>
       </list>
  </property>  
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject"></property>     
    </bean>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that Maven dependency has compile scope, the contents of that JAR are going to be available on the classpath of your application. Instead of trying to refer to the JAR to get your hands on the mapping files, get them from the classpath, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238335/how-to-config-spring-to-load-hibernate-mapping-from-jar), i.e. using `mappingLocations` and `classpath:...file.xml`.

If that doesn't work for some reason and you really need to reference the JAR file, the parameter of `mappingJarLocations` is a Spring resource. If you're not in a Servlet container, you can use `file:///path/to/jar` and if you are in a Servlet container, you can pull it from `WEB-INF/lib` as in the linked answer.